# How do I automate a saved import in a macro in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have created a macro to run a saved import (a file imported from Excel into Access 2007).  When I run the macro, the saved import runs and the following happens:

1. A "Manage Data Tasks" window pops up.
2. I have to choose from the following options: **`Run`**, `Create Outlook Task...`, `Delete`, and `Close`.
3. If I select `Run`, the next pop-up asks, "Overwrite existing table or query?"
4. I have to choose: **`Yes`** or `No`.
5. Another window pops up and says, "All objects were imported successfully."
6. I have to click the **`OK`** button.
7. I have to click the **`Clos`e** button on the "Manage Data Tasks" Window.

Is there any way that I can automate all these button clicks if they are always going to be the same?  (The bold faced buttons are the ones that I'll always be clicking.)

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport Method](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080751307.aspx) you won't have to interact with the Manage Data Tasks dialog at all.

```
   DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "YourSavedImportName"
```

You will however have to deal with the possible errors that get raised. For example if your source file is unavailable you will get an error like

> Run-time error '3011':
>
> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 
>   'Sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and the you spell its name and 
>   the path correctly.

Comment: When I do this i get a new table it does not get appended to the same table.

Comment: You'll have to recreate the Saved Import and choose **Append a copy of the records to the table** instead of **Import the source data into a new table in the current database**

Comment: I am getting only two options to download the whole table or link the table for odbc database. I nned to get the values from mysql database.

Answer (score -3):

This may be too simple, but can you use the Setwarnings:off command in your macro before you import.

Now I would like to see the macro to automate the import